# Outlook add-in office.js not loaded

Tags: outlook-web-addins, office-store

I have an Outlook add-in that simply adds a command button on Outlook, and once clicked, makes a request to my self hosted API endpoint. The add-in manifest is valid, I can add the add-in, but when I click on the button added by my add-in, Outlook tells me that it's working on my request, but that never completes. See screenshot:

[outlook add-on not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJbt9.png)

When I look at the developer console, I see that office.js cannot be loaded from my web server where my add-in is hosted. I have already added the domain name in

```
<AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>domain.com</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A ExecuteFunction based add-in command has to call `event.completed()` to notify Outlook that the execution is complete. Are you seeing the "working on my request" progress bar even after calling event.completed()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by Apache sending a too restrictive Content-Security-Policy header, which blocks the loading of office.js, any styling, and client-side requests to Microsoft resources. To fix this, I modified my Apache configuration's CSP directive to include *.microsoft.com, and 'unsafe-inline' for scripts and styling.